# Save a div as image HTML,JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save `div` as image
I have div contain Camera shot and 360 image
I try html2canavas and this does not work. it shows nothing .

```js
function Take(){               
  html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  });
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="con">
      <div id="div" style="width: 400px;height: 400px;" >
  <div
  id="cat"
  style="position: absolute;top:50px;left:  25px;"
  class="cloudimage-360"
  data-folder="cats/"
  data-filename="{index}.png"
  data-amount="30"
  data-magnifier="2"
  ></div>
  </div>
      <div id="camera" style="position: absolute;top:10px;left:  25px"></div>
  </div>

      <br><br><br>
  <button onclick="Add()" style="margin-top: 40px">+</button>
      <button onclick="Moin()">-</button>
      <br>
                 <button onclick="Up()">Up</button>
  <br>
      <button onclick="Right()" >Right</button>
          <button onclick="Left()" > Left </button>
      <br>
          <button onclick="Down()" > Down </button>
      <button onclick="Take()">Take</button>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

The problem is it shows nothing when I press Take
Here my page [Image Of my page] [image: 1]
Here When I press Take it's create `canvas` with only button without the images

[image: image about canavas created]
[Project link in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HoussemNeuer/Ldhf20sc/10/)

Comment: what does "it shows nothing" mean? Does it remove the div? Does it insert a canvas but it's blank, etc. etc.? Open your dev tools, and please update your post to explain what _actually_ happens =)

Comment: yes it's insert blanc canavas

Comment: No really, please [update your post](/help/how-to-ask). Explain what you _actually_ see happening by saying "I ran this code, it starts as ..., I click .., then dev tools shows that ..., where the documentation (here) suggests that ... ": explain it like we're 5, so that all the details are there, and we can point you to exactly what you're doing wrong (and in which context).

Comment: Done , i upload it

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what the actual DOM is: in dev tools, in the "inspector" tab, what is the tree structure before, and what is the tree structure after? Because the image you're showing sure looks like a real canvas element, just one without anything drawn on it: does the console tab show any errors? Also, help yourself out and use a stylesheet that gives canvas elements a background color, so you can tell it's there. Remember, you're debugging, make things _super_ obvious for yourself.

Comment: console not show any error

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you read your script ,it says that select html component which has id as camera (`document.querySelector("#camera"`).
 And then append this as a html canvas in body of html (`document.body.appendChild(canvas)`).

 But in your code there is nothing defined inside div with id camera :

```
<div id="camera" style="position: absolute;top:10px;left:  25px"></div>
```

So, you need to put some text/image or whatever you want to take screenshot of inside that div. And then it would add it in a canvas in html's body.

If you want to add canvas inside a div then add below lines in html and js can be used:

```
<div id="addCanvasInside"></div>  

 document.querySelector("#addCanvasInside").appendChild(canvas);
```

This is jsfiddle working example : http://jsfiddle.net/abhinav3414/6vqdsbr4/13/

Hope it solves your problem.

**Edit:** 
With the fiddle you have attached, with your webcamjs component your div now contains a video element : 
[image]

And for now, I think html2Canvas cannot generate screenshot from a video component in html, please refer below : 
[How to take screenshot of a div which contains video and canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491425/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-which-contains-video-and-canvas)

Also, You can take a copy of the current video and store it in a canvas element using the drawImage() function.
Please refer below for solution : 
[How to take a snapshot of HTML5-JavaScript-based video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760805/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-html5-javascript-based-video-player)

Comment: i have JS Function give div named camera image

Comment: <script>
         Webcam.set('constraints',{
        facingMode: "environment"
    });
    Webcam.set({
       width:450,
        height:450,
        image_format:'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality:90
        
    });
    Webcam.attach("camera");
      
    </script>

Comment: It is better you create a live example of code. Like I have done in jsfiddle and share here.